# App-Indexing Issue - Number of app pages that are indexed are going down

Tags: android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I am having an issue regarding App Indexing. I have attached a graph and i want to know why there is a decline after 5th Nov as you can see from the graph. Applinks are working completely fine (which is while we search on google it redirects to the app when we click on the link in the search page).  Any help would be much appreciated
I went through "https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/test#testing-your-completed-app" to validate my links. For some app urls it works proper but for some app urls it gives me following **"ERROR:An unknown error happened when we processed your request. Try again later."** But for those app urls linking is working proper. Please refer following crawl status graph image to understand problem.

[image]